# Why are my CSS transitions not working between defined colour variables

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I'm making an interactive SVG image that will transition between 2 or more states. At the minute I can get an immediate change by toggling the class but no transitions are occurring.

I've tried putting them into individual classes and the transitions work but this would be cumbersome.

These are the two css states I want to toggle between

```css
.weatherBackground {
  --color-stop-1:#fff;
  --color-stop-2:#6cddf7;
  --color-1:#fd4b0d;
  --color-2:#ff9b1f;
  --color-windows:#fff;
  --color-3:#ffe96b;
  --stars-opacity:0;
}

.weatherBackground.night {
  -webkit-transition:all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all 33s ease-out;
  transition:all 3s ease-out;
  --color-1:#0056e9;
  --color-2:#3995ff;
  --color-windows:#fffc07;
  --color-stop-1:#000000;
  --color-stop-2:#072254;
  --stars-opacity:1;
}
```

Referenced in the SVG like this

```
<g id="windows" fill="var(--color-windows)">
<rect width="25" height="25" y="700" x="10"/>
</g>
```

I would like to toggle between the different defined variables.
`--color-1` easing from `#fb4b0d` to `#0056e9`

EDIT:
I abandoned the idea of mass changing CSS variables. I believe it's not possible  with SVG or simply not worth the effort so I've just separate ones now for each element. Thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or a code snippet?

Comment: A quote from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33377336/10967889 "You can't do the transition from inherit to color. You have to define color before"